# My GET request is executing exactly twice

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ejs

So I'm performing a GET request in jQuery and for some it executes exactly twice. The first time it gets the appropriate data and the second time gets an empty object. Because that empty object is being passed into a EJS file, my code is throwing an error. I really don't understand why it's happening. I've tried to catch the empty object but that makes my web-app hang. I've tried to bind and the click event, but to no avail. Here is output that it is producing and the code I've written. Any help is appreciated

Output:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Listening to port 8081
app.get
reply get requested
found
[
  {
    replies: [
      'fight me bro',
      'boss main',
      'kinda slow innit'
    ],
    _id: 5e0cb67b48dfda4448c57ec0,
    msg: 'if you can',
    likes: 2,
    date: '1/1 @ 9:10',
    seconds: 51,
    __v: 0
  }
]
reply get requested
found
[]
```

You can see at the second `reply get requested`, the object logged is empty.

JQuery Code

```
    $('.bubble.sender.first.animate-bottom').on('click', function(){ // hit bubble to reveal replys
      console.log("bubble clicked.");
      var message = $(this).find('input.hiddentag').val(); // gets the message
      var replydate = $(this).find('input.hiddendatetag').val(); // gets the date

      console.log("message: " + message);

      var chat = {msg: message, date: replydate};
      console.log(chat);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/reply',
        data: chat,
        success: function(data){
          console.log("Heading to appropriate reply page.....");
          window.location.replace("/reply");
        }
      });
      return false;

    });
```

Node JS Code

```
app.get('/reply', function(req, res){
    console.log("reply get requested");
    // console.log("message: ", req.query);

    chats.find({msg: req.query.msg, date: req.query.date}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("couldn't find chat");
            throw err // crash
        }
        console.log('found');
        console.log(data);
        res.render('reply', {chat: data});

    })
})
```

EJS Code:

```
                <% for(var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) { %> <!-- earlier chats go first-->
                    <% if (i % 2 == 0) { %>
                        <div class="bubble recipient first animate-bottom">
                            <li class = "display"><%= chats[i].msg %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <i class="fas fa-heart liked" aria-hidden="true"></i> <sub><%=chats[i].likes%></sub> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <i class="fa fa-reply reply"></i>
                                <input type="hidden" id = "changeit" class = "likebutton" value = "<%=chats[i].likes%>" > 
                                <input type="hidden" class = "hiddentag" value="<%=chats[i].msg%>"> <!-- needed to get the message that was liked-->
                                <input type="hidden" class = "hiddendatetag" value="<%=chats[i].date%>"> <!-- needed to filter messages that are the same-->
                            </li>
                            <br>
                            <span>Sent: <%=chats[i].date %> </span>
                        </div>
                    <% } else { %>
                        <div class="bubble sender first animate-bottom">
                            <li class = "display"><%= chats[i].msg %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <i class="fas fa-heart liked" aria-hidden="true"></i> <sub><%=chats[i].likes%></sub> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <i class="fa fa-reply reply"></i>
                                <input type="hidden" id = "changeit" class = "likebutton fas fa-heart" value = "<%=chats[i].likes%>" > 
                                <input type="hidden" class = "hiddentag" value="<%=chats[i].msg%>"> <!-- needed to get the message that was liked-->
                                <input type="hidden" class = "hiddendatetag" value="<%=chats[i].date%>"> <!-- needed to filter messages that are the same-->
                            </li>
                            <br>
                            <span>Sent: <%=chats[i].date %> </span>
                        </div>
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>
```

Comment: The 'bubble clicked' messages appears only once on the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your server twice, both times with the `/reply` route.  Once with the ajax call and once with `window.location.replace(...)`.

You send an Ajax call to `/reply`.  That hits the `app.get('/reply', ...)` route.

Then in the success handler for the Ajax call, you do:

```
window.location.replace("/reply");
```

which tells the browser to go to the `/reply` URL.  That will again hit the `app.get('/reply', ...)` route and give you your second set of logs for that route.

So, that explains "why" you see two sets of logs and why the route is hit twice.  Now, the question is how to do what you're really trying to accomplish without hitting the server twice?   Since this is just a GET, it seems like you should probably just build the same URL that the ajax call is building and just do something like this:

```
 window.location = `/reply?msg=${message}&date=${replaydate}`;
```

or whatever it takes to properly construct the desired URL.  That will get the same data to your EJS template to construct the desired web page and then display  the result in the browser and will only call your server once.

And, then skip the Ajax call entirely because you're not using its results anyway.  The rendered web page from the Ajax call is just thrown away.  The ajax call does absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: Why do I need to skip the AJAX request? I need that data so I can use it my EJS profile.

Comment: @cjenwere4 - It sounds like you're missing some of the understanding for how the browser works and what an ajax call does and how it sends data to the server.  Your ajax call does NOTHING.  It creates a URL such as `/replay?msg=someMsg&data=someData`, sends that to your server.  Your server parses the parameters out of the URL, sends them to your EJS template and renders a web page and then returns that web page.  That web page is available to you in the success handler of your ajax call, but you do absolutely nothing with it.  It is thrown away.

Comment: @cjenwere4 - So, the ONLY thing the ajax call does of consequence is call `window.location.replace()` which just tells the browser to go to the `/reply` URL all over again which sends that request to your server which renders a web page without your parameters and then displays that in the browser.  What you really want to do is to just do `window.location = \`/reply?msg=${message}&date=${replaydate}\`;` which will send the exact same data as the ajax call to your server, but will then display the results in the browser (which is presumably what you want).

Comment: Oh I understand it!! I've been tackling this problem for hours, thank you so much sir.